# transform a dictionary from key:value to value:number of occurences

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary as follows

```
d = {1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 9, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 9}
```

How can I get a dictionary of the **most common** values sorted in descending order?

So I would expect

```
res = {9: 4, 8: 3, 7: 3}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 9, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 9}
>>> Counter(d.values())
Counter({9: 4, 8: 3, 7: 3})
>>> Counter(d.values()).most_common()
[(9, 4), (8, 3), (7, 3)]
```